# AngularJS validating my form

Tags: javascript, angularjs

After validating my form, I need to submit it.

I need to submit the form to another mocked API endpoint which returns true or false depending on whether the answer provided was correct, and display this response in the UI.

Is it possible to implement this to archive it? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/fK6NL8G6zgaTp7d4zM4P?p=preview)

html:

```
<my-form ng-app="CreateApp" ng-controller="mainController">
  <form ng-submit="submitForm()" novalidate>
      <fieldset>
        <div ng-repeat="field in result.fields">
          <label for="{{field.type}}">{{field.label}}</label>
          <input ng-if="field.type != 'radio'" ng-required="{{field.required}}" value="{{options.value}}" type="{{field.type}}">

          <div ng-if="field.type == 'radio'">
            <div ng-repeat="option in field.options">
              <input type="{{field.type}}" 
                     ng-model="richestClub"
                     value="{{option.value}}">{{option.label}}</br>
            </div>

          </div>



          <form-error ng-show="{{!!field.errorMessages.required}}">{{field.errorMessages.required}}</form-error>
          <form-error ng-show="{{!!field.errorMessages.invalid}}">{{field.errorMessages.invalid}}</form-error>
        </div>
      </fieldset>

      <button type="button" ng-click="onValidate(); return false;"> Validate</button>
      <button type="submit" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid"> Submit </button>
    </form>

</my-form>
```

JS controller:

```
var myApp=angular.module('CreateApp', []);

myApp.controller('mainController', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('form.json').success(function(response) {
    $scope.result = response;
    console.log($scope.fields);
  });



  $http.get('form.json').success(function(response) {
    $scope.result = response;
    var fields = response.fields;
    $scope.richestClub = fields.answer.options[0].value;
    console.log($scope.richestClub);
    console.log($scope.fields);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely possible. However your code has several errors.

You use userForm as the form variable but don't specify it. It should be like

```
<form name="userForm">
```

in order to access it in JS.

The same for the fields - if you want to access their errors you should provide their name
like `<input type="" name="{{field.name}}" />` and then you can access validation results through "userForm[field.name]".

Add callback to submit button: `<button type="submit" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid" ng-click="onSubmit(userForm)"> Submit </button>`

Comment: nice one, are you able to provide a plunker please with the mocked API endpoint ?

Comment: check this one with your suggestions http://plnkr.co/edit/fK6NL8G6zgaTp7d4zM4P?p=preview